# Hide or minimize window in javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have a script code in vb.net environment which is calling file from path but when i call the file the window remain opened i want to hide it.
My code is bellow

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "openfile", String.Format("window.open('/Reports/September Sowing Report Area-1/September Sowing Report Area-1 {0}.ods');", DD4.SelectedValue), True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the focus back to the main window after opening the other one in the JavaScript code.

For example:

```
 window.open( .... ); self.focus();
```

Also, you might be able to use the [blur](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp) method:

```
var newWindow = window.open( ... );
newWindow.blur();
```

Let me know if this works for you. Behavior might depend a bit on the browser...